# como paginar una list en angular

Tags: javascript, angular, lista

Quiero utilizar este componente

```html
<mat-paginator [length]="100"
              [pageSize]="10"
              [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]">
</mat-paginator>
```

Esto es el codigo que tengo en la vista de html

```html
<mat-list role="list">
  <mat-list-item role="listitem">numero 1</mat-list-item>
  <mat-list-item role="listitem">numero 2</mat-list-item>
  <mat-list-item role="listitem">numero 3</mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

y esto en es lo que tengo en el archivo ts

```html
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

/**
 * @title Basic list
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'list-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'list-overview-example.html',
})
export class ListOverviewExample {}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo necesitas usar el output `(page)` del componente para obtener los datos de paginacion.

```
<mat-paginator 
    [length]="listaCompleta.length" 
    [pageSize]="cantidadPorPagina" 
    (page)='paginar($event)'
    [pageSizeOptions]="opcionesDeCantidades">

</mat-paginator>
```

Y despues trabajas estos datos en tu logica:

```
paginar(paginacion: any) {
    let actual = paginacion.pageIndex * paginacion.pageSize
    this.listaParaMostrar = this.listaCompleta.slice(
      actual,
      actual + paginacion.pageSize
    );
  }
```

Te dejo un [ejemplo funcional aqui](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qao62p)

---

## Edición

Para mantener los botones de ultima y primera pagina solo agrega `showFirstLastButtons` en el paginador.

El ejemplo esta actualizado.

Comment: Si funciona, pero desactiva los controles de siguiente e ir al ultimo registro como se ve en la imagen que agregue, la puedes revisar porfa

Comment: @Arturo No aparece ninguna imagen.

Comment: Es la ultima imagen

Comment: @Arturo Edite la pregunta

Comment: Si, ya esta bien, excelente